# Override entity manager in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

**Updated to reflect discussion**

I want to implement some custom logic for selecting the correct entity manager. I thought this would be as easy as overriding the doctrine.class parameter, extending Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry and overriding the getManager() method. However, when I do, I get the following error:

```
ErrorException: Warning: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nmevent/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 119
```

Here's the code:

```
<?php

namespace NM\Bundle\MultiTenantBundle\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry;

class TenantRegistry extends Registry
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */

    public function getManager($name = null)
    {
        if (null === $name) {
            $name = $this->defaultManager;
        }

        $managers = $this->getManagers();

        if (!isset($managers[$name])) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Doctrine %s Manager named "%s" does not exist.', $this->getName(), $name));
        }

        return $this->getService($managers[$name]);
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What's in `$this->name` when you throw the exception?

Comment: As the error says, it's undefined meaning it doesn't exist. The same is true for $this->managers when I try to dump it. Makes it seem like something hasn't been properly initialized, but I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get nonexistent property `name` of the `TenantRegistry` class on line **21**:

```
                                                           here
throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(                 ↓
    'Doctrine %s Manager named "%s" does not exist.', $this->name, $name));
```

**UPD**:

Property `name` is defined in `AbstractManagerRegistry` class and it has private access. So, you are unable to get this property directly. Use the `getName()` method instead.

Comment: I get that. What I don't get is why it's non-existant since the method I'm overriding is an exact duplicate of the original.

Comment: Using getName() allows the Exception to be thrown. However, that means that the $this->managers is also non-existant. When I temporary store the managers using getManagers() and pass the temp variable to getService I get "ErrorException: Warning: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nmevent/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 119"

Comment: In what class/method the exception thrown? Also, update your question with edited data.

Comment: Never mind - I see now that the getManagers() method does not return what I want. When replacing it with getManagerNames() it seems to work.